# Hibernate: MethodConstraintViolation is deprecated

Tags: java, hibernate, validation

I see also from the jboss doc that https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.3/api/org/hibernate/validator/method/MethodConstraintViolationException.html is deprecated, however it does not specify with what it has been substituted. 
Anybody knows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First at all, *Deprecation* doesn't mean that it does not work. If you take a look at the [Hibernate Validator Migration Guide](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateValidatorMigrationGuide) will see the next evolution of method validator, that clarifies there is no alternative in your case,

For version 4.3

> The package org.hibernate.validator.method with its containing classes
> is deprecated **without alternative for now**. In Hibernate Validator 5
> this package will be removed to align with Bean Validation 1.1. The
> method level validation methods will then be available via
> javax.validation.Validator.

Here is the [deprecation list](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.3/api/index.html?deprecated-list.html) for Hibernate Validator 4.3.

If we continue with version 5.0.x, there is more info about it,

> - The custom method validation feature has been replaced by the method
>   validation specfied by Bean Validation 1.1.
> - Methods for method validation moved from javax.validation.Validator to
>   MethodValidator ([BVAL-310](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/BVAL-310), [HV-629](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HV-629))
> - Renamed javax.validation.MethodValidator  to ExecutableValidator; javax.validation.Validator#forMethods() renamed to forExecutables() ([BVAL-355](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/BVAL-355)).

The road shows that *method validation of parameters and return values* had been standardized as part of Bean Validation 1.1 and Hibernate Validator 5 final releases support it.

Now if you want to migrate to HV5/BV1.1, I suggest you to follow the [HV5 documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.0/reference/en-US/html_single/) (maybe you want to go directly to *Declaring and validating method constraints* section)

Answer (score 0):

In Javadoc it says that

> ... Will by replaced by equivalent functionality defined by the Bean Validation 1.1 API as of Hibernate Validator 5.